# AngularJS ng-submit not working with PhoneGap iOS app

Tags: iphone, forms, angularjs, cordova, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to use the native keyboard "Go" button in my login form in a PhoneGap iOS app made with AngularJS, when the user click on the "Go" button i want to launch the "connect()" function of my controller. the "ng-submit" directive is not working :

```
<form ng-submit="connect(mail,password);" >
        <input iscroll-bug type="mail" ng-model="mail" placeholder="E-mail">
        <input iscroll-bug id='password' type="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Mot de passe" >
        <div ng-hide='loader' class="yellow_btn" ng-click="connect(mail,password);" ><p>Se connecter</p></div>
        <img style='width:30px;' class='center' ng-show='loader' src='img/ajax-loader.gif' /><br/>
</form>
```

I think maybe the solution is in create a new Directive to force the action of the "onSubmit" event, i tried something like this :

```
// Other directive i Have
.directive('submitForm', function ($timeout, callbackOnSubmit) {
  return {
    link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.submit(function () {
        callbackOnSubmit();
      })
    }
  }
});
```

and use it like this :

```
<form submitForm="connect(mail,password)" >
```

Not working so I'm probably getting it wrong in my directive, is anyone already have this similar issues and solve it ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a `<input type="submit">` with a display:none style, when i display it, it's working so just use visibility:hidden and it's working just fine with the native keyboard "go" button and ng-submit